# Sonar-SQL Queries in Java

Tags: sonarqube

We can use SQL query in **.html.erb** files and **.rb** files to retrieve data from Sonar DataBase. How can I use SQL queries in Java files to retrieve data from sonar. Is there any way to do this. Any examples.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What data do you need to retrieve? Your question is too broad.

Comment: sonar providing certain API's to access their database in Ruby. i want to access it using JAVA

Comment: OK. Are those query statements available? So are you asking how to use queries in Java? If so, you can look at JDBC.

Comment: I know how to query in JAVA. I'm developing a plugin in sonar. For developing those plugins they are providing some API's. only that ways we can access the database

Comment: Not very familiar with Ruby. But are the source files which contain the APIs available? Are the query statements themselves available?

Answer (score 0):

You should not query directly the DB as it is not an API. Please use Sonar API instead.

I understand that currently, some Ruby templates directly query the DB through Active Record, but this is evil as the DB may change without notice. Consequently, we will remove this feature sooner or later and provide a real API to access resources on the Rails side.

**The database is not an API.**